# failed to install hashlib in python3.5 - error code 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to install `hashlib` on my mac. `pip` doesn't work, and `easy_install` also does not work. 
Here is the error:

```
  Collecting hashlib
    Using cached hashlib-20081119.zip
      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    import setuptools.version
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
    from email import utils
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/email/utils.py", line 28, in <module>
    import random
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/random.py", line 45, in <module>
    from hashlib import sha512 as _sha512
  File "/private/var/folders/nw/flrm4y0d499fk5xr2ppxk4sr0000gn/T/pip-build-lv720o4k/hashlib/hashlib.py", line 80
    raise ValueError, "unsupported hash type"
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
  Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/nw/flrm4y0d499fk5xr2ppxk4sr0000gn/T/pip-build-lv720o4k/hashlib/
```

Any further suggestions would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `hashlib` is part of the Python standard library. You don't need to install it.

Comment: Oh, but when I tried to use any function from the library it gives me an error saying `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'update'` (this was in the case of using the update function)

Comment: Then please post the original error (with your code and a proper description), not the problem with your approach to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is very old, but I stumbled upon it on Google because I had the same problem just now. In my case, I was working with an AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and my environment got that exact same cryptic error message about a syntax error inside hashlib.

For AWS, the trick is NOT including all your imports in the requirements.txt file, but only things you would normally have to pip install. That includes modules like hashlib, string, and random.

So for others who stumble upon this question: there is no need to install hashlib, just import it and you're ready to go!

Answer (score -1):

sudo apt-get install libffi-dev g++ libssl-dev

via https://github.com/bigchaindb/bigchaindb/issues/24#issuecomment-183370814